# Android - External button input

Tags: android

I am making an Android app which has one button on the screen, which runs a method when I click on it. But now I want to have an external button calling that method. I thaught of using the usb port and let the app listen to the data input of the usb port, but I've read that's practally impossible. An other solution I am thinking of is use that same usb port, but simply listening to the current on the usb port. In example, I could make the button change the resistance when I press it, which will change the current with the same voltage applied.

Now for the programming part, is it possible to measure the current flowing through the usb port? Or is there maybe an easier way of using external input buttons?

Thanks in advance,
Jeroen D.